# How to create a bash script that will lower case all files in the current folder, then search/replace in all files?

Tags: bash, search, replace

**Answer #1:** I ended up starting from scratch, and I was able to piece something together that works! Might not be the most efficient, but it does the job.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.php
do
#Check to see if the filename contains any uppercase characters
    iscap=`echo $file | awk '{if ($0 ~ /[[:upper:]]/) print }'`
    if [[ -n $iscap ]]
    then
#If the filename contains upper case characters convert them to lower case
        newname=`echo $file | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'` #make lower case
#Perform various search/replaces on the file name to clean things up
        newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/---/-/')
        newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/--/-/')
        newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/-\./\./')
        newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/there-s-/theres-/')
#Rename file
        echo "Moving $file\n To $newname\n\n"
        mv $file $newname
#Update all references to the new filename in all php files
        `sed -i "s/$file/$newname/g" *.php`
    fi
done
```

**Answer #2:** Although it doesn't check for upper case characters and just tries to convert everything (giving an error on files that are already lower case), if you know you're only going to be processing files with upper case characters you can use the version that **aqua** submitted.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.php
do
    newname=`echo $file | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
    newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/---/-/')
    newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/--/-/')
    newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/-\./\./')
    newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/there-s-/theres-/')
    mv "$file" "$newname"
    for f in *.php
    do
        sed -i "s/$file/$newname/g" *.php
    done
done
```

Thanks for everyone's help on this!

---

**The Original Question & Additional Information**

I'm using some software to create documentation for an open source software project, except it outputs the HTML files with upper case characters, which isn't recommended for SEO. So, I'm trying to write a bash script that will change all .html files to lower case, and then search/replace

So, I want to turn this:

This-Is-The-Output.html

Into this:

this-is-the-output.html

And then search all the files in the current directory for "This-Is-The-Output.html" and replace it with "this-is-the-output.html".

I've been trying to piece something together based on what I've found online, but I just can't get it to work. I'm about as inexperienced with writing bash scripts as someone can be, so I figured I would turn to SO to see if someone could help out.

This is what I'm currently working with...

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.php;
   icleaned=`echo $i | sed s/./\\./g`;
   inew="$(tr [A-Z] [a-z] <<< "$icleaned")";
   sed -i 's/$i/$inew/g' *.php;
   do mv $i $inew;
done
```

Line 3: Do a search and replace for special characters, like "."

Line 4: Assign the clean, lower case string to $inew

Line 5: Search/replace all references of the old filenames to the new filenames

Line 6: Move the files from their old filename to their new filename

The errors I'm getting are:

```
line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `icleaned=`echo $i | sed s/./\\./g`'
line 3: `   icleaned=`echo $i | sed s/./\\./g`;'
```

I tried just echoing icleaned to see if the first step was working properly, but I get the exact same error.

I even tried commenting out everything except for the inew= line:

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in *.php;
#  icleaned=`echo $i | sed s/./\\./g`;
   inew="$(tr [A-Z] [a-z] <<< "$i")";
   echo $inew;
#  sed -i 's/$i/$inew/g' *.php;
#  do mv $i $inew;
done
```

And I'm still getting the "syntax error near unexpected token" error.

```
line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `inew="$(tr [A-Z] [a-z] <<< "$i")"'
line 4: `   inew="$(tr [A-Z] [a-z] <<< "$i")";'
```

So obvious the script is messed up in many, many ways.

Any help someone could offer up would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please describe how it's not working?  Try `echo $i $inew` instead of `mv $i $inew` to see if the values of `$i` and `$inew` are what you expected

Comment: For one thing, you can't stack statements in the `for` loop like that. A `for` loop takes a list of strings after the keyword `in`. It's not like a `while` loop, which allows a list of commands before the `do` keyword.

Comment: @Lorkenpeist - I've added some extra detail to the post.

Comment: @chepner - All the examples I found were using for, and like I said I'm pretty clueless when it comes to bash scripting, so all I can really do is try to piece something together from what I find.

Comment: You need to add `do` after the `for` line. It's stupid, but required.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 Thanks for that, I had no idea! Now that I have a working version, I'm not even going to try this on the old version... I really don't want to know if I wasted that much time over a "do" :P

Comment: Should the answer be separated into, perhaps, an `answer`... so that the question can still be seen?

Comment: @icedwater I'm not sure what you mean (sorry, I'm very new to SO). I can't find a way to mark a section as the answer, but the original question and all the details I posted are still there, I just posted the answer(s) at the top so people would know right away that this was solved and they didn't spend their time answering again.

Comment: Well @greg-chetcuti, I suggested an edit which removed [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17182743/1091386) leaving only the question. It wasn't accepted, which is fine, but the question could be obscured with this approach... and who's to say the best solution has already been found?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.html
do
    lowercase=`echo $file | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
    mv "$file" "$lowercase"
    for f in *.html
    do
        sed -i "s/$file/$lowercase/g" "$f"
    done
done
```

Change `*.html` to `*.<extension>` if you're working with something other than html files.

Comment: You really want to be using double-quoted strings to avoid nasty accidents: `mv "$file" "$lowercase"` and `sed -i "s/$file/$lowercase/g" "$f"`

Comment: It's not the most efficient, but I was just able to piece something together that works (updated in my original post).

@aqua - I may play around with your version and work in the extra search & replaces, as yours seems much more efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Updated as per comments from [@JS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/970195/js) to use -exec:

```
find . -name '*[A-Z]*' -type f -exec bash -c 'echo "{}" | mv "{}" "$(tr A-Z a-z)"' \;
```

You can try rename as well if you have the correct version installed. Check your man page for rename:

```
rename 'y/A-Z/a-z/' *
```

A one-liner with mv to search and rename files with uppercase in filename only using find.

```
for i in $(find . -name '*[A-Z]*' -type f); do mv "$i" "$(echo $i|tr A-Z a-z)"; done
```

Comment: `for loop` can be avoided if you use `-exec` option of `find` to trigger `mv`. This will break on file name with spaces.

Comment: Variant with 'y/A-Z/a-z/' didn't work, just didn't do anything at all. What does mean "correct version installed"? I've got it just standard system's one "rename from util-linux 2.24.2" for "rename -V". The first variant was perfect though, the one-liner I looked for.

Answer (score 0):

**This is really the answer the OP came up with after some work, but I thought I would separate it here so it doesn't clutter up the question.**

I ended up starting from scratch, and I was able to piece something together that works! Might not be the most efficient, but it does the job.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.php
do
#Check to see if the filename contains any uppercase characters
    iscap=`echo $file | awk '{if ($0 ~ /[[:upper:]]/) print }'`
    if [[ -n $iscap ]]
    then
#If the filename contains upper case characters convert them to lower case
        newname=`echo $file | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'` #make lower case
#Perform various search/replaces on the file name to clean things up
        newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/---/-/')
        newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/--/-/')
        newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/-\./\./')
        newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/there-s-/theres-/')
#Rename file
        echo "Moving $file\n To $newname\n\n"
        mv $file $newname
#Update all references to the new filename in all php files
        `sed -i "s/$file/$newname/g" *.php`
    fi
done
```

Although it doesn't check for upper case characters and just tries to convert everything (giving an error on files that are already lower case), if you know you're only going to be processing files with upper case characters you can use the version that **aqua** submitted.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in *.php
do
    newname=`echo $file | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]'`
    newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/---/-/')
    newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/--/-/')
    newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/-\./\./')
    newname=$(echo "$newname" | sed 's/there-s-/theres-/')
    mv "$file" "$newname"
    for f in *.php
    do
        sed -i "s/$file/$newname/g" *.php
    done
done
```

Thanks for everyone's help on this!